# How to apply fake slant for Bold Italic font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I want to apply Bold Italic as a Fake slant, since the font does not have the bold Italic version

Note: This font have Italic version

How to get the Bold Italic as a Fake slant?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,%
                ItalicFont = SpectrumMTStd-Italic.otf,%
                BoldFont = SpectrumMTStd-SemiBold,%
                BoldFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2}
                BoldSlantedFeatures={BoldItalicFont = SpectrumMTStd-SemiBold,FakeSlant=0.2}
                ]
                {SpectrumMTStd.otf}%%


\begin{document}

\textbf{Bold font}

\textbf{\textsl{Bold Italic font}}

Roman font

\textit{Italic Font}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to define the bold italic font, you should use the `BoldItalicFont` key. I don't have your font, so I use some other fonts (and add color) to demonstrate the principle:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont = TeX Gyre Heros,%
             BoldItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.2,Color=FF0000}
             ]
                {TeX Gyre Termes}%%


\begin{document}

\textbf{Bold font}

\textbf{\textsl{Bold Italic font}}

Roman font

\textit{Italic Font}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update.